# Fetch data to php file returning null value

Tags: php, fetch-api

I'm trying to test and learn how fetch works so I want to send some data from javascript to a php file, my problem is that I can't retrieve the data (in the php file), only getting a null response.

I'm using POST but I have tried with GET with the same result

As a side note, in console the conection in network only appears after I press F5 , as I understand it, to work should be already when I open Test.php.

***datosJS.js***

```
let datos = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
      username:"Jonathan",
      email:"jonathan@gmail.com",
      password:"123456"
  })
}

fetch('Test.php',datos)
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(resp =>{
    console.log(resp);
})
```

***Test.php***

```
<script src="datosJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //I use this to call "datosJS.js" to receive the data here in Test.php

<?php

 $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    var_dump($body);
    
?>
```

I understand PHP is on server side and JS on client side and both of them run in different times, nevertheless I'm having troubles to find the solution to this problem.

Thank you for your help !

** Edited a small change in fetch which now let me see the data in console

Comment: `response.json()` : your PHP returns a string that is not a JSON string (contains HTML (`<script>...`), whitespaces, and var_dump() output).

Comment: Are you loading the JS file in Test.php? From the posted code, it's unclear. If you want to return data from PHP, that file shouldn't contain _any_ other output (no HTML etc) than your response (which should be json encoded).

Comment: Yes sorry I just edited the comment. I'm loading the JS file in Test.php. The idea is when I open Test.php to receive the data from the JS file.

Comment: If you script JS into test.php that then calls test.php to get a result, calling test.php, doesn't that endanger the existence of the entire universe (aka loops infinitely)?

Comment: Even if it worked, you can't use `var_dump` to get parseable JSON. It's serialized, just use `echo`.

Comment: Don't worry Skip the existence of the universe is safe so far (as far I've seen, its runs only once on page load and thats it). I have made a change in fetch, now I can see the data in console but I still get a NULL in the actual page.

Just to note, "echo" prints in console "Array" while "var_dump" shows in console the whole array content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I managed to get the solution to this, explanation is below:

**datosJS.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

let datos = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
      username:"Jonathan",
      email:"jonathan@gmail.com",
      password:"123456"
  })
}

fetch('Test.php',datos)
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(resp =>{
console.log(resp);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resp; 

    //document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = resp; // works as well as getElementById
    
})
}
```

**Test.php**

```
<script src="datosJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class="Section" id="results" name="results">

            <?php

            $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
            $nombre = $body['username'];

            echo  $nombre;
            echo  '</br>';
            print_r($body);
  
            ?>
```

Below I will mark what was lacking in the original code:

- In datosJS.js  **document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resp;** and wrap everything in **window.onload = function() {}**
- In Test.php add the **id="results" name="results"** to a *div*, *section* or whatever to receive from the innerHTML.

I hope it helps someone in the future. Cheers